# MATLAB and imageJ: lossless work on double images (imadjust, strechlim, imwrite)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagej, contrast

I'm working on a stack of "double" images. I am trying to do some contrast stretching and save the images in a lossless way which I can open later in imageJ for analysis.

I'm trying to conserve detail in the image so I'm concerned with data loss if I convert to uint8 etc. I would otherwise do:

```
    for i=1:num_images
      image=uint8(imageset(:,:,i));
      imadjust(image,stretchlim(image),[]);
      saveloc=[somefolder,num2str(i),'.tif'];
      imwrite(image,saveloc);
    end
```

I wan't to do the equivalent of this and create a folder of contrast adjusted images (im guessing 32 bit tiff?) which I can then load in imageJ in a view-able way.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. I think you want to process some images before saving them in lossless technique. is your question, what is optimal Matlab function can save an image without losing data?

Comment: Its a 2 part question: 1. how do I do contrast stretching on a double image? and 2. how do I save a double image in a lossless way which I can then open in imageJ?

Comment: what do you mean by `double` image? it's just like `uint8` for `imadjust`, if your input is double will get the output in same data type. 2. `imwrite(image, saveloc, 'tif','Compression','none');`

Comment: its a double precision image

Comment: TIFF does support double float pixel data, but few programs know how to read those. I'm not sure if MATLAB's `imwrite` writes floating-point data to TIFF. A simple alternative is writing the pixel data as CSV. Another is using ICS ([libics](https://github.com/svi-opensource/libics) comes with MATLAB functions, and there's an ImageJ plugin also).

Comment: Can you add an image (double float) to your question so we can try help you better?

Comment: @CrisLuengo He can use `save()` instead of `imwrite` to save the image in `.mat` file. see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/333229-how-can-i-save-an-image-and-read-it-again-without-change-its-value#answer_261416

Comment: Why don't you do the contrast stretching in ImageJ right away?